# Oracle plsql error

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, plsql

Does anybody knows what that error is pointing?

```
ORA-06550: line 1, column 129:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "," when expecting one of the following:

   ( - + case mod new not null <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable>
   continue avg count current exists max min prior sql stddev
   sum variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval
   date <a string literal with character set specification>
   <a number> <a single-quoted SQL string> pipe
   <an alternatively-quoted string literal with character set specification>
   <an alternatively
```

Comment: Please include the `sql` itself. It's way easier to spot an error then...

Comment: *"what that error is pointing*": that error is pointing to line 1, column 129. You will have to show us your code.

Comment: Well that the problem, I'm going trough debugger and nothing, no error, I have console app trough witch I'm calling web service, when i call app it returns that error, but trough debugger nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at character number 129 on the first line. The developers didn't output that information because it was useless. They output it because it should point you to the exact place where the error occurred.

This is a syntax error of some sort, such as two commas in a row, or a keyword misspelt, or a dozen other possibilities.

The code at the specified location is what you need to look at, or to show us, so that you can figure out the problem.